# Better, more effective, alarms, for Android (persistent alarm every five minutes with text confirmation of completion and parental controls)

Tags: parental-control

I would like to know whether it is possible to design an alarm that can only be dismissed by writing a text message into the alarm.

The text message needs to be specific, such as:

"I have prepared (what I needed to do here).

The text to type is presented above the text box, and the user needs to type it in to dismiss the alarm.

The app checks that the text is the same, as above (as given, and can be set by the parent, above the app).

This way, the alarm, is not only presented, once, in the morning, in a low volume, dismissed, and forgotten.

It rings, continuously, every five minutes, until the user types in they have done what they needed to do (once done).

The app is set and controlled through a parental control (present as an app on another phone).

This way, the user, cannot turn it off.

The app is dismissed, not when your get the reminder, but when you have completed the task at hand (and keeps ringing every five minutes, until you complete the task).

When you complete the task at hand, the parent gets a notification.

Thank you for your support.

I was wondering how this can be done.

Please migrate my question to software recommendations if more appropriate there.

This app, may be the only effective way to ensure extremely distracted people...

Thank you.

Comment: It would certainly be possible to write an app to do this. Given the specific and unusual requirement, getting someone to do that will likely be necessary.